# Is it preferred to define a separate plural complexType for multiple singular elements

Tags: xsd

Is there any established standard for inlining trivial plural complexTypes vs. defining them separately?

In detail: When defining some XML schemas I frequently encounter cases where I want one element to contain multiple child elements of the same single type. For example a schema which describes a table in a database has a `fields` element which can contain one or more `field` elements. I can either create an inline complexType within the definition of the plural `fields` element:

```
<xs:element name="fields" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="field" type="table-field" 
                  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Or I can separately define a trivial `fields` type and use that:

```
<xs:element name="fields" type="table-field-collection" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">

<!-- Elsewhere: -->
<xs:complexType name="table-field-collection">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="field" type="table-field" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The first approach creates a slightly more messy markup with anonymous types, while the second creates lots of extra trivial complexTypes. Is there a concensus on which approach is preferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really an established standard for this. There are really three choices:

1. "fields" must be defined as a complex type and reused (table-field-collection above)
2. "fields" is an element with an anonymous sub-type
3. There is no fields element. Instead, "field" simply repeats within the parent element.

I have specified modelling guidelines for a number of firms and used all of these patterns. More recently, I'm tending towards the third - the encapsulating `fields` element does not really have any semantic meaning, other than making a nice grouping when viewing documents in some graphical tools. If you were to process this using something like JAXB, you'd probably annoyed that `fields` is there - one more thing that can be null.

If you want to ask yourself the one relevant question from a technical point of view, then it is this: do you want to be able to inherit from table-field-collection and override it using `xsi:type`, or reuse it? If yes, go for the complex type. If no, go for whatever you prefer style-wise.